# SSO using SAML + C# .net

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, saml, identityserver3, kentor-authservices

I know this question has asked many times on StackOverflow and might be duplicate. I have been reading almost 2 days on SSO, SAML, Identity Server , Kentor Authservices. Now I am able to understand each individual term but I am still not able to connect the dots.

I want to implement Single Sign On (SSO) in asp.net using C# SAML.

- How to implement Identity provider? Do I have to implement on my own? (I will authenticate user against database)
- How to implement service provider?

This might looks silly but I am new to this. Any pointer or help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to use SAML? Is it for supporting a legacy system? anyway, if you would like to use `identityServer3`, it supports `wsfed` via a wsfederation plugin, here is a [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/SelfHost%20(InMem%20with%20WS-Fed)/SelfHost) that demonstrates how to make identity server supports wsfed using self-host , and this is a [wsfed client](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/Clients/MvcOwinWsFederation) sample, hope they help

Comment: Thanks for reply. I will look into it. By the way The decision of using SAML is taken by client so sticking with it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use an OOTB IDP.

e.g. ADFS, simpleSAMLphp, shibboleth, idsrv3 (with Kentor SAML plugin).

For the SP, you need a client side SAML stack as per [this](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/2013/06/saml-saml-connectivity-toolkit.html).